# Find the center bit of a binary number

Tags: functions, polynomials, binary, binary-operations

Let's say you have a set of binary numbers (or strings, whatever) $n$ each of odd length. How does one derive the algebraic (or arithmetic) form function $f(n) = b$ where $b \in \{0,1\}$ and is equivalent to the center  digit of $n$, which by definition of odd numbers, must exist.

I feel like this is incredibly easy but I don't know the vocabulary to search for a  solution online. Note: I am looking for a general formula, not a programming solution.

Comment: I feel like this is relatively easily solved in Boolean algebra, which is a subset of classical algebra, so shouldn't it theoretically have a closed formula?

Comment: You can do this in any base,  provided you know the length of the number.  Suppose you have a number $n$ of length $2k + 1$. Dividing by $10^k$would result in a number which have "middle digit" as its last digit and some "decimal" place,  so you just have to round it below. Lastly,  just take the last digit,  which can be done by doing mod $10$. Of course 10 here in some base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ f_n(a) = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}} \right\rfloor \mod 2 $$

Comment: this is it, thanks!  do you have a source or a citation / reference for this?